# What is the difference between ceilMinute and ceilMinutes in PHP Carbon?

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, php-carbon

In the Carbon.php source file that comes with Laravel 8 it shows

```
 * @method        $this               ceilMinute(float $precision = 1)                                                     Ceil the current instance minute with given precision.
 * @method        $this               ceilMinutes(float $precision = 1)                                                    Ceil the current instance minute with given precision.
```

Basic testing shows that given input "2021-11-26 11:25:10.000000", both functions round it up to "2021-11-26 11:26:00.000000".

And I want to know is there any difference between these two functions?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is no difference. Carbon provides this for all its functions. See here https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/blob/2c074edef62859a7a99ca46b7bade664c6243b74/src/Carbon/Traits/Date.php - search for minute and see all available as minute and minutes.

Comment: Indeed, plural/singular are aliases so you can have it grammatically correct with either: `->ceilMinute(1)` or `->ceilMinutes(5)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: they're 100% equivalent.

Carbon implements almost everything using [magic methods](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call). The implementation of `__call()` basically [strips trailing `s`](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/blob/2.55.2/src/Carbon/Traits/Date.php#L2564):

```
/**
 * Dynamically handle calls to the class.
 *
 * @param string $method     magic method name called
 * @param array  $parameters parameters list
 *
 * @throws UnknownMethodException|BadMethodCallException|ReflectionException|Throwable
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function __call($method, $parameters)
{
    // [...]
    $unit = rtrim($method, 's');
```

... and uses that to [fetch a value](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/blob/2.55.2/src/Carbon/Traits/Date.php#L2597) from the [units list](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/blob/2.55.2/src/Carbon/Traits/Date.php#L580):

```
    if (\in_array($unit, static::$units)) {
        return $this->setUnit($unit, ...$parameters);
    }
```

```
protected static $units = [
    // @call setUnit
    // @call addUnit
    'year',
    // @call setUnit
    // @call addUnit
    'month',
    // @call setUnit
    // @call addUnit
    'day',
    // @call setUnit
    // @call addUnit
    'hour',
    // @call setUnit
    // @call addUnit
    'minute',
    // @call setUnit
    // @call addUnit
    'second',
    // @call setUnit
    // @call addUnit
    'milli',
    // @call setUnit
    // @call addUnit
    'millisecond',
    // @call setUnit
    // @call addUnit
    'micro',
    // @call setUnit
    // @call addUnit
    'microsecond',
];
```